# Apply function that applies to all rows except last row

Tags: python, pandas

The below code creates a function that correctly drops all rows with 0 values.
However, I want this function to apply to all rows, EXCEPT the last row in df.
How do I adjust this function?

```
def read_df(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, na_values=['', ' '])
    # Drop useless junk and fill empty values with zero 
    df = df.drop(['row_num','start_date','end_date','symbol'], axis=1).fillna(0)
    df=df[df!=0].dropna()
    return df
```

Edit: I want to highlight that IF the last row does NOT contain NAs or zeroes, there is no reason to append the row back because it was never removed to begin with.  This is simply to reappend the last row when it did have a zero or NA.

The objective is to apply the function above (i.e., removing 0s or NAs) to all rows prior to the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the last row by slicing after dropping the na, due to the object still having the data before the = (i.e.):

```
df=df[df!=0][:-1].dropna().append(df.iloc[-1])
```

The [:-1] should avoid a duplicate when you have non 0 data in your last column.

Comment: Thanks.  Why wouldn't df[df!=0].dropna().append(df.iloc[-1]) be sufficient?

Comment: Your right, you don't need to slice there, i've updated the answer

Comment: @ZJAY You’re not removing the last row in that snippet?! So the reason it isn’t sufficient is because not only does it seemingly not work, you’re duplicating the last row.

Comment: Oh and I believe the original solution here was incorrect. You were removing the last of the nonzero rows, instead of removing the last row of the DataFrame before applying the condition.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the current solution also appears to be incorrect.

Comment: If the last row has no `0` or `NaN`, this solution will duplicate the last row.

Comment: What would you propose as the solution?

Comment: Thanks for the catch - I updated the question with edit.

Comment: I'm sure i can come up with a better solution if it's not working, what changes would help make it work for you? I'm open for chat to help formulate one

Comment: They pointed out that if the last row has no 0 or NaN, the solution duplicates the last row.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: it doesn't if you use df=df[df!=0][:-1].dropna().append(df.iloc[-1]) , but would that work with the logic your looking for. i'll reread the question to see if i can come up with something for that case. One issue with dropna, is that it seems to drop regardless if you have a clause not to include an index location with one.

Comment: @ZJAY i think this one worked the right way:  df=df[df!=0][:-1].dropna().append(df.iloc[-1]), i tested with a last column with NA's and no NA's and it doesn't duplicate if there are no NA's.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, you just need comparing on a slice of dataframe without the last column and append the last column into the result of `dropna`

```
def read_df(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, na_values=['', ' '])
    # Drop useless junk and fill empty values with zero 
    df = df.drop(['row_num','start_date','end_date','symbol'], axis=1).fillna(0)
    df=df[df.iloc[:-1] != 0].dropna().append(df.iloc[-1])
    return df
```